# Convert String to System.IO.Stream

Tags: c#

I need to convert a String to System.IO.Stream type to pass to another method.

I tried this unsuccessfully.

```
Stream stream = new StringReader(contents);
```

Comment: I wasn't aware MemoryStream was the same at Stream.

Answer (score 463, accepted):

Try this:

```
// convert string to stream
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contents);
//byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(contents);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
```

and

```
// convert stream to string
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware MemoryStream was the same as Stream.

Comment: @xbonez: `Stream` is not the same as `MemoryStream`. `MemoryStream` inherits from `Stream`, just like `FileStream`. So you can cast them as `Stream`...

Comment: Just a note: Streams implement IDisposable, so you need a using wrapper around them to be safe.

Answer (score 56):

To convert a string to a stream you need to decide which encoding the bytes in the stream should have to represent that string - for example you can:

```
MemoryStream mStrm= new MemoryStream( Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( contents ) );
```

MSDN references:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55%28v=VS.100%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx

Answer (score 10):

```
System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( contents));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "asasdkopaksdpoadks";
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Comment: Using ASCII encoding makes panda sad... :(

Answer (score -8):

this is old but for help :

you can also use the stringReader stream

```
string str = "asasdkopaksdpoadks";
StringReader TheStream = new StringReader( str );
```

Comment: `StringReader` is not a stream.

Comment: Built in classes that derive from System.IO.Stream are listed here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @zetoff, confused by StreamReader?