# Save text from textbox to memorystream?

Tags: c#, .net

Hi i'm newbie in C# developer. I would like to save a text-file to database. I watched some videos on Youtube. They use Memorystream to save image:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Now i try to save a text from a textbox? Can i have similar way to do it?
Thank you

Comment: Saving a string to a memory stream?  See [SO question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047064/convert-string-to-system-io-stream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myTextBox.Text))
```

Comment: Yes it works thanks. Btw do you know you take this text from memorystream to a textbox?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78181/how-do-you-get-a-string-from-a-memorystream

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Try something like this.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text), 0, textBox1.Length);
```