# HttpContext.Current.Response to Download file in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have below code in asp.net

```
 GetObjectResponse resp = Media.ReadS3Object("data", strKey);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.ResponseStream);

            //Prompt download:
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = resp.ContentType; // "text/csv;";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fname));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(UTF8Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sr.ReadToEnd())));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

it downloads file, how can I achieve samething through mvc.
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to post data to the server?  Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963253/uploading-csv-file-using-c-sharp-asp-net-mvc

Comment: No, I have file path, just want to download

Comment: what happens when you try this code in your MVC project?

Comment: You can also have a look at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult

Answer (score 0):

Set the ActionResult to return a file.

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string strKey) {
    GetObjectResponse resp = Media.ReadS3Object("data", strKey);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.ResponseStream);


    return File(sr, resp.ContentType, fname);
}
```