# cannot send fileupload.postedfile.inputstream as an attachment - ERROR: cannot convert system.io.stream to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I need to send a pdf as an attachment. I am using a html template as mailbody. My problem is the error displayed while trying to send the attachment as follows.

```
email.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream), pdffilename);
```

The FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream is the error code.

My full code is displayed below:

```
private void send_job_notification(string name, string app_email, string job_id, string job_title, string experience,string pdffilename)
    {
        string to = "aaa@bbb.com";
        SmtpClient smtp_server = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage email = new MailMessage("aaa@bbb.com", to);
        smtp_server.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp_server.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp_server.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("aaa@bbb.com", "PASSWORD");
        smtp_server.Port = 25;
        smtp_server.EnableSsl = false;
        smtp_server.Host = "zzz.bbb.com";
        email.From = new MailAddress("aaa@bbb.com");
        email.To.Add(to);
        email.Subject = "New Job request submitted for company";
        email.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream), pdffilename);
        email.IsBodyHtml = true;
        string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/emailnewtemplate.html");
        StreamReader str = new StreamReader(FilePath);
        string MailText = str.ReadToEnd();
        str.Close();
        string line1 = "<h4>Dear Management</h4>";
        string line2 = "<h4>A new job request has been receieved. The applicant details are as follows</h4>";
        string table_open = "<table class='table table-responsive-sm'>";
        string row_1 = "<tr><td>Name : </td><td> " + name + " </td></tr>";
        string row_2 = "<tr><td>Email : </td><td> " + app_email + " </td></tr>";
        string row_3 = "<tr><td>Job ID : </td><td> " + job_id + " </td></tr>";
        string row_4 = "<tr><td>Job Title : </td><td> " + job_title + " </td></tr>";
        string row_5 = "<tr><td>Experience : </td><td> " + experience + " </td></tr>";
        string table_close = "</table>";
        string line3 = table_open + row_1 + row_2 + row_3 + row_4 + row_5 + table_close;
        string htmlbody = line1 + line2 + line3;
        MailText = MailText.Replace("[#####HERE#####]", htmlbody);
        email.Body = MailText;
        smtp_server.Send(email);
   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String to System.IO.Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047064/convert-string-to-system-io-stream)

Comment: Thankyou but it does not answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a wrongly placed bracket is your problem, It looks like you tried to use the constructor [Attachment(Stream, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.attachment.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Mail_Attachment__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_String_) of the `Attachment` class but you supplied only the stream. the constructor of `Attachment` class that accepts only one parameter is expecting a string that's what the error message says

correct it as :

```
email.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, pdffilename));
```