# Save XML content to a variable

Tags: c#, xml

The following code creates a physical XML file called *employees.xml*. But I don't want to create a physical file. Instead, I want to save the XML content to a variable. How can I modify the following code to save the XML data into a variable and not have it physically created?

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("employees.xml"))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("Employees");

    foreach (Employee employee in employees)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Employee");

        writer.WriteElementString("ID", employee.Id.ToString());
        writer.WriteElementString("FirstName", employee.FirstName);
        writer.WriteElementString("LastName", employee.LastName);
        writer.WriteElementString("Salary", employee.Salary.ToString());

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write to MemoryStream and use

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream);
```

You code would be modified like

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();    
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("Employees");

    foreach (Employee employee in employees)
    {
       writer.WriteStartElement("Employee");
       writer.WriteElementString("Id", employee.Id.ToString());
       writer.WriteElementString("FirstName", employee.FirstName);
       writer.WriteElementString("LastName", employee.LastName);
       writer.WriteElementString("Salary", employee.Salary);
       writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
}
string strXml = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray())
```

*You can select the encoding you need.*

Answer (score 1):

Just a small modification in your code would give the desired output. You can use the StringWriter class and the final XML will be saved inside xmlString variable.

```
string xmlString = null;
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented; // if you want it indented

    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("Employees");

    foreach (Employee employee in employees)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Employee");

        writer.WriteElementString("ID", employee.Id.ToString());
        writer.WriteElementString("FirstName", employee.FirstName);
        writer.WriteElementString("LastName", employee.LastName);
        writer.WriteElementString("Salary", employee.Salary.ToString());

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();

    xmlString = sw.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use XmlWriter, I would create a DOM object in memory - ideally with LINQ to XML, which will let you express the whole thing as a query:

```
var xml = new XDocument(new XElement("Employees"),
     employees.Select(e => new XElement("Employee",
         new XElement("ID", e.Id),
         new XElement("FirstName", employee.FirstName),
         new XElement("LastName", employee.LastName),
         new XElement("Salary", employee.Salary))));
```

You can now manipulate this XML (adding or removing elements etc) and when you want to save it to a file (or stream it across the network or whatever, you can do so easily).

If you want the *string* representation in a variable, you can just use `ToString`:

```
var xmlAsText = xml.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I will stay with same solution from @Adil. But want to add changes in your code:

Instead of writing a xml object manually(every member of class) you can use a `XmlSerializer` class. With this class you can then `Deserialize` xml object back to class instance

Second - if you want keep data of `Employees` in xml object and maybe later to change something in there, than you can use a `XmlDocument`. Here a code:

```
XmlSerializer _xSerialize = new XmlSerializer(_employees.GetType());
MemoryStream _mstream = new MemoryStream();

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(_mstream))
{
    _xSerialize.Serialize(_mstream, _workers );
}

XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(_mstream);
```

P.S. For Serialization working fine both classes Employees and Employee must have default constructor(with no parameters) and properties you want to xml must be public.

This what kind of classes I used for testing:

```
public class Employees
{
    public List<Employee> Workers { get; set; }

    public Employees()
    {
        this.Workers = new List<Employee>();
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public Int32 ID{ get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    public float Salary{ get; set; }

    public Employee() { }

    public Employee(Int32 id, string fname, string lname, float salary)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.FirstName = fname;
        this.LastName = lname;
        this.Salary = salary;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using some stream you could write into a StringBuilder instance: [XmlWriter.Create-Methode (StringBuilder)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/66dybzaw.aspx)